# Storing File URI and Checksum to check if the file was changed in future

Tags: security, cryptography

right now application is storing a file data in database and we are considering instead to store a link (http, ftp, etc) to the file and its checksum. We will only provide a service and the service consumer is supposed to provide the URI and its checksum.
As we do not want to store the file, we won't be able to calculate a checksum, checksum is needed because we want to provide some kind of proof that the initial file has not been tampered with.

Is this applicable, if we require client apps to calculate checksum lets say in MD5 or SHA-256 would it give the same result on all environments (linux, windows, macOS, etc.), would it differ by the algorithm calculating the checksum. Or should we receive the file data and calculate its checksum in our app to make sure that a strong and unified checksum calculation method is applied, and provide a tool to calculate it again when user has access to file so they can verify that it is the original file.

Comment: as long as you use the same algorithm you will be ok. think about linux distros that come with a signature file to prove it hasn't been tampered with

Comment: As I mentioned I will be asking consumers of the service to provide the checksum.

Comment: yes, my point is that anyone can validate the sig, because the algorithm is standard

Comment: How do you check that the file hasn't been altered at a later time? Do you ask the service consumer to again provide you with a checksum, or do you intend to calculate the checksum yourself at that point?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau No, I do not. Multiple parties will be using that file, if in the future, they disagree that the file that they used at some point has been changed by the provider of the file, I intend that the checksum will be used if it has been or not. The stored file might be changed (becuase it is stored in a different domain), but the original checksum they provided cannot be changed.

Comment: @hazimdikenli: If you intend to be some kind of (legal) arbiter in determining if a file has changed, then your service is completely worthless if you depend on the provider of the file to generate the checksums. What is stopping them from changing the file but providing you with only the original checksum to disprove their change?